# Append bootstrap-vue modal to app template

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I use [**bootstrap-vue modal**](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/modal/):

In my project [**codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-cfp1b?fontsize=14):

**Template:**

```
<template>
  <b-button variant="link" class="btn-remove" @click="removeItemFromOrder(index)">
    Remove item
  </b-button>
</template>
```

**Script generating modal with custom content:**

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  methods: {
    removeItemFromOrder: async function (position) {
        let self = this

        const h = this.$createElement

        const titleVNode = h('div', { domProps: { innerHTML: '<h2>Remove this item?</h2>' } })

        const messageVNode = h('div', { class: ['modal-complete'] }, [

          h('div', {
            domProps: {
              innerHTML:  '<h2>Remove this item?</h2>'+
                          '<span class="popup-meta">'+
                            'Are you sure you want to remove this item?'+
                          '</span>'
            }
          })
        ])


        this.$bvModal.msgBoxConfirm([messageVNode], {
          title: [],
          centered: true,
          modalClass: 'success-popup',
          hideHeader:true,
          footerClass: 'd-flex justify-content-center align-items-center',
          cancelVariant: 'outline-danger',
          okVariant: 'danger',
          okTitle: 'YES',
          cancelTitle: 'NO',
          ststic: false
        })
          .then(async function (result) {
            if (result) {
              self.currentOrder.items.splice(position, 1)
              await self.sync()
            }
          })
          .catch(err => {
            // An error occurred
          })
      },
  }
};
</script>
```

Now bootstrap modal after open append to `body`. So, that's why I have a **quastion**:

How I can append bootstrap-vue modal to `#app` or another template\ tag?

**P.S:** only for `this.$bvModal.msgBoxConfirm` with `then` ... So as not to create unnecessary methods ... 
due to amount of popups with diffetent logic

Comment: What you want to do actually?

Comment: So as not to create unnecessary methods

Comment: due to amount of popups with diffetent logic

Comment: Check out this issue: https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/1108

Comment: I already saw this issue, but I hope there is still a solution to this problem!  Any other solutions or modal plugins for creating multiple modals without additional method

Comment: I trust `static: true` isn't good enough for what you need?

Answer (score 9):

It's not posible
If you read the code, it just append direct the Modal to the body

https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/blob/dev/src/components/modal/helpers/bv-modal.js#L162

```
  const div = document.createElement('div')
  document.body.appendChild(div)
  msgBox.$mount(div)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issues and came up with a workaround. I'm using a scoped version of bootstrap, where each bootstrap class is prefixed with `.bootstrap-scope` so that bootstrap styles don't interfere with other things on the page. That means having the modal appended directly to the body wouldn't work, as it wouldn't inherit the bootstrap styles from within `.bootstrap-scope` (and I can't add the bootstrap-scope class to the body).

I already have jquery loaded, so my solution is to simply capture the $bvModal.show() event by immediately hiding the modal that's newly created and appended to the body (which won't show up correctly) and then appending the modal to the container I want. The catch is that the modal needs to be removed from the custom container when it's hidden, because the show event will recreate it and there will be issues.

```
show_modal: function(viz) {
    var vm = this;              

    vm.$bvModal.show(vm.modalId); 
    $(`#${vm.modalId}___BV_modal_outer_`).hide(); 

    setTimeout(()=>{
        $(`#${vm.modalId}`).appendTo('#' + vm.containerId); 
        $(`#${vm.modalId}___BV_modal_outer_`).show(200); 
    }, 50); 

}



hide_modal: function() {
    this.$bvModal.hide(this.modalId}); 
    $(`#${this.containerId} .modal`).remove(); 
}
```